# Calculating the highest value across a line drawn over a 2D-Array

Tags: arrays, 2d

I am trying to find the highest value across a line in a uniform 2D Array e.g. *300x300*. The line is not necessarily a line that can be drawn horizontally, vertically or at a 45 degree angle. It can be at a different line, so I need to think think of a way to find out which cells in the array my line intersects.

What is the best approach (and hopefully most efficient) that I should take to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found this algorithm that solves my problem [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)